# Is this the best way to see my running processes?

Tags: command-line, process

So obviously the title says it all. Is this the best way to view my running processes?

```
ps -u whoami
```

Comment: I don't know, is it? What's "best"? As it stands, your question is entirely a question of opinion and such questions are [off topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) here. Are you maybe asking for alternatives? Also, that command won't actually work, you meant `ps -u $(whoami)`

Comment: What about `top`, `ps -A` or `ps -A | less`? All valid... true that the question is a matter of opinion but perhaps you intend to ask for the cleanest, most human-readable form or maybe a way to list processes for only a particular user?

Comment: @terdon well since it errors out the answer is a valid "no" :D

Comment: Seeing as how I use this command it does not give any errors ;)

Answer (score 2):

That is not a valid command so: no.

```
ps -u $(whoami)
```

would be a valid method but since $USER equals to the current user

```
ps -u $USER
```

is shorter and less consuming. You can also do

```
top -U $USER
```

for a real time method (it will refresh the processes) and ordered by %CPU.

Or

```
pstree $USER
```

for a tree like view.